# Cells connected with reverse polarity in parallel

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]

How exactly are the corresponding equations derived here?

Answer (score -1):

The direction of an unknown current in a circuit to be solved can be assumed to be in either direction.  If the assumption was wrong, the current will show a being negative in the solution.